# LinkButton not rendered completely

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, command, render, asplinkbutton

I have this function that I call in page int event

```
 Protected Function RenderLB(text As String, Id As String, argument As String) As [String]
        Using Lb = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton
            Lb.Text = text
            Lb.ID = Id
            Lb.Attributes.Add("runat", "Server")
            Lb.CommandName = "RedirectFillsession"
            Lb.CommandArgument = argument
            Dim StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            Using stringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter(StringBuilder)
                Using htmlTextWriter = New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)
                    Lb.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter)
                End Using
            End Using
            Return StringBuilder.ToString()
        End Using
    End Function
```

the returned value is anchor but CommandName and CommandArgument are not rendered 
what should I do to render the CommandName and CommandArgument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommandName and CommandArgument are never rendered into the output HTML, they are used in the accompanying JavaScript.

Also, you should add your control to the controls collection instead of rendering it manually. That way you can be sure its part of the entire Page Life Cycle.

```
Controls.Add(Lb)
```